# OpenGL ES Vertex buffer objects don't work with my drawTexture method

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have tried for some time now to use the Vertex Buffer Objects to render a texture on the screen. I have a working function here that use the classic method:

https://github.com/batiste/sdl2-opengl-es/blob/master/common.c#L546

This first method works. A bit down there is the Vertex Buffer modified version:

https://github.com/batiste/sdl2-opengl-es/blob/master/common.c#L586

I have tried many different ways, checked all the inputs and search on this site for similar problems but without success. I need a fresh, expert eye on this.

The second part of the question is about performance. I want to use then to display some simple textures on my Android phone. What kind of speed up can I expect from using vertex buffer? Is it really worth using for 2 triangles?

Comment: `glVertexAttribPointer`s last parameter is a _byte_ offset into the buffer. So looks like there's a `sizeof(GLfloat)` factor missing.

Comment: @stefan-hanke Thanxs that was it. Really quick and accurate answer.

Comment: Didn't write an answer because last time, I did misinterpret the specs. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`glVertexAttribPointers` last parameter is a byte offset into the buffer. So looks like there's a `sizeof(GLfloat)` factor missing.

Comment: I would like to vote your answer up but I only have 12 reputation yet. Missign 3 points.